# Are WinRT .net classes Managed code?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

In .Net4.5 we have namespaces starts with "system" and 'WinRT & Metro style API' namespace starts with "windows".

My question is, are the classes that fall in "WinRT/Metro API" (classes in windows namespace) Managed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think now I have the answer,

The metro style API's are subset of CLR so it is managed.
The WinRT API are at OS level (Kind of COM based) so those are UnManaged.

However, both starts with same namespeace "windows.xxxxx.xx"